# Building C Runtime along with program ANTLR

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I want to write a program using antlr (target C language) and I want to ship the library (C runtime distribution) to the package so that it can use on other machine without installing antlr on that machine. I've downloaded the latest version of this runtime on this link http://www.antlr.org/download/C . Could anyone please tell me if I can do that? Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can link it statically but how to do this depends on your platform. For Linux with gcc or llvm you can do:

```
g++ main.c -Wl,-Bstatic -lantlr3c -Wl,-Bdynamic -l<other dynamic libraries>
```

Anything after -Bstatic will be included in the executable.

Depending on your jurisdiction, the C target license requires that you include the license text with your program in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used the C target but have used the C# target. I assume they work in a similar way.

You will need to deploy the C runtime library with your program as the generated parser and lexer will use functions in this library.

You don't need to install Antlr itself eg AntlrWorks or any .jar files